# trying to add more strings after printing one list using Listiterator method but its not printing nor getting any error

Tags: java

New names are not added to the list

```
import java.util.*;

public class ListItrators34 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>(10);
         name.add("Nishant");
         name.add("Suparna");
         name.add("Dinesh");
         name.add("Gagan");
         name.add("Aparna");

         ListIterator<String> itr = name.listIterator(); 
          while (itr.hasNext())// This method will print the list in the same order as "Top to Bottom"
              System.out.println(itr.next());
           name.add("Akshay");
           name.add("Rohan");
           while(itr.hasNext())
               System.out.println(itr.next());
```

The new names are not adding to the previous list

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the same iterator after inserting new data. Instead you can use a variable to record the position.

```
ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>(10);
name.add("Nishant");
name.add("Suparna");
name.add("Dinesh");
name.add("Gagan");
name.add("Aparna");

int index = 0;
while (index < name.size())
    System.out.println(name.get(index++));

name.add("Akshay");
name.add("Rohan");

while (index < name.size())
    System.out.println(name.get(index++));
```

Comment: This answer. The 'itr' is only initialized once. Iteration methods are a bit outdated too, i would use the following: for(String nameValue:name){              System.out.println(name);}

Comment: @W vd L I thought op wants to print out the new data rather than the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

The names are in the list alright. It's because the result of the second call to `itr.hasNext()` returns false. You've already run through the iterator so there is no more next. Avoid reusing iterators.

Comment: Thank you Surfman... but by saying "no more next" means we can only run once through Iterator. If so, should I use LinkedList?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Iterators are mostly designed to run over a collection once. When you're done, you should discard them. If you want to continue after adding elements, you need to keep track of the last index read, and then use a for loop to iterate from that index to the new end.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong. The iterator is created when `Akshay` and `Rohan` have not been inside the list. Although the iterator is used to iterate through the elements in the list, but the iterator has no idea that there is more things in the list now.

Moreover, the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) has already said that the iterator is *fail-fast*.

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.

Therefore, the API does not expect the iterator to run when the underlying list is changing.

Answer (score 0):

You get a `ConcurrentModificationException` because you modified the list, after which you re-used the same `ListIterator`.

Problem can be solved by re-initializing the iterator:

```
ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>(10);
name.add("Nishant");
name.add("Suparna");
name.add("Dinesh");
name.add("Gagan");
name.add("Aparna");

ListIterator<String> itr = name.listIterator();
while (itr.hasNext())// This method will print the list in the same order as "Top to Bottom"
    System.out.println(itr.next());
name.add("Akshay");
name.add("Rohan");

itr = name.listIterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
    System.out.println(itr.next());
```

But do you realy need to use a `ListIterator`? A `for` loop would probably be more appropriate, and more clear:

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(10);
names.add("Nishant");
names.add("Suparna");
names.add("Dinesh");
names.add("Gagan");
names.add("Aparna");

for (String name : names) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
names.add("Akshay");
names.add("Rohan");
for (String name : names) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ward, I have already run this program with the help of for loop in LinkedList but trying to see what is the result if I use ListIterator for the same. It compiled but the next command of itr.next() returned false and I had no Idea why and how It can be rectified.